# How to make two way communication using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, two-way

The Scenario is I have a win App which is client of a service.Other Win applications are also using that service.If on any client application a button is clicked it searches the application using button caption in service if found then notify that application.Using Timer in all application is one way but I don't want to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reentrant duplex communication with WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048181/reentrant-duplex-communication-with-wcf)

Comment: which is only one of many, many duplex-related questions. you can also google for bare-bones duplex wcf (disclaimer: first link is probably mine)